# NoClassDefFoundError at edu/knowitall/openie/openIECli

Tags: java, scala, noclassdeffounderror

hi i am getting an error while running the OpenIE scala code in eclipse

https://github.com/knowitall/openie

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: edu.knowitall.tool.postag.Postagger: method ()V not found
    at edu.knowitall.tool.postag.ClearPostagger.(ClearPostagger.scala:15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with scala project structure but looks similar to maven one.

Two points,

edu/knowitall/openie/openIECli, I see the class name is wrong should be edu/knowitall/openie/**OpenIECli** (case-sensitivity) . Although it should be a typo error, but better to check this one too.

which class are you trying to execute.

Also, you can refer to this link: [How to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

I suspect some problem with the build path, but need more details to look into.

Comment: i had fix few error but after i am getting anther type of error is


 edu.knowitall.tool.postag.Postagger: method <init>()V not found

Comment: Make sure the dependencies are pointing to the right versions. You get this error when code was compiled against X version of depedency and in CLASSPATH Y version is used, you should reconcile the same. Right now it looks to me the depedencies are messed up. Did you try to recompile to whole code, I bet you would get compile time errors too.