# how to solve NoClassDefFoundError in a java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, jena

I'm trying to read an owl file from the java servlet. But i'm getting the above error.
I thought the jar file is missing and tried to add the jar file again in WEB-INF/lib. But still i'm getting the same error. Please help me solve this error. Here is the servlet code:

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
    import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
    import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

    /**
    * Servlet implementation class testServlet
    */
    @WebServlet("/testServlet")
    public class testServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
    * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
    */
    public testServlet() {
     super();
     // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)            throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:/MTech/semantic validation/code/travel.owl");  String file = request.getParameter("file");
    file=file.replace("\\", "/") ;
    System.out.println(file);




    OntModel model =  ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
    model.read(fis, null);
    String output = "<p>loading file done</p>";
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println (output);
     }

    }
```

and here is the error i'm getting

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/ModelFactory
kanive.testServlet.doPost(testServlet.java:54)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
kanive.testServlet.doPost(testServlet.java:54)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: You need to redeploy in order the servlet container take the change.

Comment: What's your structure of your application? What's inside your `WEB-INF/lib` folder now?

Comment: Are you sure the jar file you have contains the class you need?  How are you deploying?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to recompile the code and re-deploy (assuming that the JAR is obviously in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder).