# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Tomcat with Maven dependency

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, libsvm

I have problem on Tomcat startup. I added dependencies to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
    <artifactId>weka-dev</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
    <artifactId>LibSVM</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

IntelliJ doesn't have problem with this, i can import classes from this dependencies in editor. Problem starts when i deploy it on tomcat, and i get exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator

Why tomcat cant see this class in runtime?

Comment: Refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011108/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-com-google-api-client). The question is downvoted and closed but the answer is valid.