# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.AWSS3V4Signer

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark

How to specify "signature version 4" in spark configuration while launching spark shell in terminal?

I have configured spark with three parameters:

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint","s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "");
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "");
```

I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.AWSS3V4Signer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: of course another duplicate question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011108/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-com-google-api-client