# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.net.sll.HostnameVerifier

Tags: java

I am running a java program that I have probably run at least 25 times, but am now receiving the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.net.sll.HostnameVerifier.

Could anybody shed light on the error so that I can troubleshoot?

Comment: Have you changed the JRE? If I search for that class in the java 11 javadoc the package has changed to `javax.net.ssl`. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier.html

Comment: Have you changed the CLASSPATH?

Comment: I suggest to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25011152/2137378