# Grails: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver

Tags: grails, groovy, noclassdeffounderror, ggts

When I'm, trying to create and execute new project in GGTS using grails 2.3.8 I have this issue:

Loading Grails 2.3.8

```
Error |
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.getAvailableScripts(GrailsScriptRunner.java:817)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:427)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:421)
Error |
    at org.grails.ide.api.impl.GrailsConnectorImpl.executeCommand(GrailsConnectorImpl.java:160)
Error |
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.run(GrailsProcess.java:130)
Error |
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.main(GrailsProcess.java:93)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
```

How it can be solved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm facing this issue in GGTS tool while creating executing new projects.