# WICKET: Can't instantiate page using constructor when using DatePicker

Tags: java, constructor, datepicker, wicket

This time I have problem on putting DatePicker on my wicket Page.

My code is follows:

```
public class StateDB extends BasePage {
    private Date date = new Date();
    public StateDB() {
        Form form = new Form("form");
        DateTextField birthDate = new DateTextField("birthDate", new PropertyModel<Date>(
                this, "date"), new StyleDateConverter("S-", true));
        PickDate datePicker = new PickDate();
        datePicker.setShowOnFieldClick(true);
        datePicker.setAutoHide(true);
        birthDate.add(datePicker);
        form.add(birthDate);  
        add(form);
    }
}
```

When I run it on server and link to this page I'm getting Exception:

```
Last cause: org.apache.wicket.markup.head.HeaderItem
WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public kz.company.myPackage.controller.StateDB()'. Might be it doesn't exist, may be it is not visible (public).
```

But as you can see constructor of my class is public

```
public StateDB() {
```

There is stacktrace

```
Complete stack:

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public kz.company.myPackage.controller.StateDB()'. Might be it doesn't exist, may be it is not visible (public).
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:196)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:68)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:47)
     at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:103)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:264)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:165)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:105)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:224)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:167)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:784)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:255)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:188)

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:177)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:68)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:47)
     at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:103)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:264)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:165)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:105)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:224)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:167)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:784)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:255)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:188)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/wicket/markup/head/HeaderItem
     at kz.company.myPackage.controller.StateDB.<init>(StateDB.java:72)
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:177)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:68)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:47)
     at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:103)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:264)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:165)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:105)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:224)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:167)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:784)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:255)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:188)
```

Comment: Is this stack trace complete? see your console log in IDE, may be there is more significant explanation. This is too broad exception, that you have posted.

Comment: I've added complete StackTrace

Comment: Ok, the real exception is: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/wicket/markup/head/HeaderItem. It means, that your classloader could not find this class. It's about your project settings. There is a lot of information about this problem in google, for examlpe check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17974068/2168532

Answer (score 0):

Something is going wrong in you constructor. When an exception is throw in the constructor, Wicket catches it an displays that message. Does the field 'date' have a getter and setter? These are required for the PropertyModel in DateTextField.