# Deploy JAX-RS (Jersey 2.13) Web Service using Tomcat 7 javax/inject/Singleton

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, jax-rs

I have my web services in `Jersey 2.13` with `Tomcat 7`. But when I try to run in server I have this error:

```
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Singleton
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.ContractProvider$Builder.<clinit>(ContractProvider.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.ContractProvider.builder(ContractProvider.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.modelFor(ComponentBag.java:476)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.access$100(ComponentBag.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag$5.call(ComponentBag.java:408)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag$5.call(ComponentBag.java:398)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.registerModel(ComponentBag.java:398)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.ComponentBag.register(ComponentBag.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.register(CommonConfig.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:448)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
```

I forget something?

Comment: Try here:

[How to Solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Tomcat 7 includes CDI "out of the box", so you need to bundle a CDI implementation in your WAR file if you want to use it. JBoss Weld is the reference implementation for CDI, you it's probably simplest to use that one. If you're using Maven, stick something like this in the `dependencies` section:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

See [this article](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/configuring-cdi-with-tomcat-example) for details.