# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after some time

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I have running an application (3rd party, not selfprogrammed) on tomcat. After some days I get an `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error insome situation. After a restart of the JVM it runs fine again.

What could be the reason ? Doesn't the classloader loads all classes at start ?

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/cognos/bux/service/atom/provider/cm/AtomUtils
com.ibm.cognos.bux.service.atom.provider.cm.providers.impl.contentmanager.DefaultAtomProvider.createSearchPath(DefaultAtomProvider.java:150)
com.ibm.cognos.bux.service.atom.provider.cm.providers.impl.contentmanager.DefaultAtomProvider.doGet(DefaultAtomProvider.java:185)
com.ibm.cognos.bux.service.atom.provider.cm.providers.BaseAtomProvider.handleRequest(BaseAtomProvider.java:52)
com.ibm.cognos.bux.service.atom.provider.cm.ContentManagerAtomProvider.handleRequest(ContentManagerAtomProvider.java:71)
com.ibm.cognos.bux.service.atom.ModelATOM.handleRequest(ModelATOM.java:232)
com.ibm.cognos.bux.service.atom.ViewATOM.handleRequest(ViewATOM.java:90)
com.ibm.cognos.bux.BUXControllerBaseImpl.mvcHandleRequest(BUXControllerBaseImpl.java:154)
com.ibm.cognos.bux.service.atom.AtomService.handleRequest(AtomService.java:55)
com.ibm.cognos.bux.http.ServiceRequestHelper._executeRequest(ServiceRequestHelper.java:80)
com.ibm.cognos.bux.http.ServiceRequestHelper.executeRequest(ServiceRequestHelper.java:50)
com.ibm.cognos.bux.service.main.ViewDHTMLInputStreamResolver$2.callImpl(ViewDHTMLInputStreamResolver.java:481)
com.ibm.cognos.bux.service.main.ViewDHTMLInputStreamResolver$2.callImpl(ViewDHTMLInputStreamResolver.java:1)
com.ibm.cognos.bux.service.main.BUXCallable.call(BUXCallable.java:34)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace.

Comment: stacktrace added, thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: No I would say not. After a restart the class seams to be loaded, otherwise I could not execute my specific functionality after the restart. I am aware about the NoClassDefFoundError when the class is missing in the classpath and would not aks if thats the problem.

Comment: Try referring this if that helps - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the Jar file containing the class com/ibm/cognos/bux/service/atom/provider/cm/AtomUtils is not present in the classpath and if present if not loaded by the Tomcat's class loader.

Comment: I clearly stated that after a restart it works fine. So it can't be that the class is missing in the classpath. I also would not ask this, because there are 1000 of answers for that kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the classloader loads all classes at start ? - NO

Classes are loaded on demand. When AtomUtils class was required in DefaultAtomProvider.java ( line 150 ) it was not available.

What could be the reason ?  -  Most probably jar containing AtomUtils is missing.

Comment: But then why it works after a startup. The class must be there, otherwise it would work never.

Comment: Class was there at compile time so you were able to start application. But at runtime class jvm is not able to find class

Comment: Important for you is "Classes are loaded on demand" , see some reasons behind this at http://mindprod.com/project/noclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [Oracle NoClassDefFoundError Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html):

NoClassDefFoundError is thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.

The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

The reason here depends on your build-path, maybe you have differents versions of the same jar file?