# Cannot run java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I'm using `eclipse juno` in an `ubuntu` machine. Recently I uninstalled openJDK and installed `Oracle jdk`. After that I cannot run any project in eclipse. It gives `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. Those programs can be compiled and run from the terminal. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: If @KickButtowski 's link doesn't help can you link to the library that you used.

Comment: @B Rad what do you mean?

Comment: @KickButtowski I have seen this issue once before but the JDK came from SourceForge and that was the problem.  Just making sure it's not something dumb.  I would expect the link you provided would solve the issue.

Comment: @B Rad I used JRE system Library JavaSE-1.6

Comment: @BRad have u opened up the link to see if it helps or not?

Comment: Is it so hard to do some research before posting a question here?