# How to create word doc using apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to create a word document using apache POI but I  am getting noclassdeffound error I have done so far this:

```
import java.io.File;   
import java.io.FileOutputStream;   
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;   
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;   
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;   
public class DocFile {   
public void newWordDoc(String filename, String fileContent)   
   throws Exception {   
 XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();   
 XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph = document.createParagraph();   
 XWPFRun tmpRun = tmpParagraph.createRun();   
 tmpRun.setText(fileContent);   
 tmpRun.setFontSize(18);   
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\"+filename + ".doc"));   
 document.write(fos);   
 fos.close();   
  }   
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
   DocFile app = new DocFile();   
   app.newWordDoc("testfile", "Hi hw r u?");   

 }   
}
```

Comment: post exception stack  please.

Comment: Does it compile? Have you added the poi jars to your class path at runtime?

Comment: Take a look at this answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Answer (score 0):

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
       XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
       XWPFRun tmpRun = paragraph.createRun();
       String folder = "E:/New folder/";
       String filename = "newDocx.docx";
       File f = new File(filename);
   
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(folder + filename));
       doc.write(out);
       System.out.println("_ok");
       doc.close();
```