# NoClassDefFoundError: opennlp/tools/chunker/ChunkerModel

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

Got this error while trying opennlp chunking:

> NoClassDefFoundError: opennlp/tools/chunker/ChunkerModel

Here is the basic code:

```
import java.io.*;
import opennlp.tools.chunker.*;

public class test{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{  
                ChunkerModel model = null;
                InputStream modelIn = new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");
                model = new ChunkerModel(modelIn);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any NLP-specific reasons here, so just check [tutorials](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-how-to-solve-no-class-def-found-error/) about NoClassDefFoundError, for example:

> Verify that all required Java classes are included in the
> application’s classpath. The most common mistake is not to include all
> the necessary classes, before starting to execute a Java application
> that has dependencies on some external libraries.
>
> The classpath of the
> application is correct, but the Classpath environment variable is
> overridden before the application’s execution."

or [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror).

In particular, check that you have appropriate (and only one) version of opennlp jar in your classpath.

*it is not a good style to import all content of the package (by using wildcard) - instead, use IDE's support: e.g. ctrl+shift+o in Eclipse (ctrl+alt+o in IDEA) automatically resolves all needed imports.