# How to load a 'ParserModel' and where to place the "en-parser-chunking.bin" file in my Web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, inputstream, opennlp

I'm getting an error while running my java web application. I have one servlet class and one class for Apache openNLP text analyzing. When I run my code (submit my form data to servlet) I get below error code in my browser

[image: Error in my Browser]

Also it shows below exception details in eclipse console.

[image]

Below is my project structure and I have placed the "en-parser-chunking.bin" file in highlighted area.

[image: Project structure]

Is there any better way to place my "en-parser-chunking.bin" file?

Comment: How did you attached the OpenNLP library to the application?

Comment: I just downloaded it from the site and paste in this highlighted location

Comment: Similar question answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311650/noclassdeffounderror-opennlp-tools-chunker-chunkermodel

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

**First** part of the answer:

1) Place the `en-parser-chunking.bin` into the `WebContent/WEB-INF/classes` or `WebContent/WEB-INF/resources` folder of your Eclipse project. These are directories in which the instance of `WebappClassLoaderBase` is allowed to load resources from at runtime of a web application.

2) With this code snippet (which is shortened for brevity):

```
String parserModelPath = "/WEB-INF/resources/en-parser-chunker.bin";
ParserModel model = new ParserModel(servletContext.getResourceAsStream(parserModelPath));

if(model!=null) {
    // From here, <model> is initialized and you can start playing with it...
    // Creating a parser
    Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
    // Parse some things here 
    // ...
}
```

you should get a working `Parser` at runtime. For reference, see JavaDoc for [ServletContext#getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) and this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108434/howto-load-a-resource-from-web-inf-directory-of-a-web-archive).

**Second** part of the answer:

1) Place the `opennlp-tools-<opennlp-version>.jar` file into `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` or reference it in the Web-App's class path of your project setup. Thus, the library and its classes, such as `opennlp.tools.parser.ParserModel`, can be loaded and used at runtime of your project.

2) Re-bundle your `war` archive and redeploy it to your Tomcat's `webapps` directory.

Hope it helps, see also my [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32164962/2849346).