# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

i am getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error for Constant_Country class, that is exist inside `com.mi.uVite.model` package.

Class is exist still it says `NoClassDefFoundError`. How can i overcome this issue?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mi.uVite.model.Constant_Country
        at com.mi.uVite.db.MIDatabaseHandler.createCountryTable(MIDatabaseHandler.java:911)
        at com.mi.uVite.db.MIDatabaseHandler.onCreate(MIDatabaseHandler.java:632)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
        at com.mi.uVite.db.MIDatabaseHandler.rowCount(MIDatabaseHandler.java:570)
        at com.mi.uvite.BackGroundIntentService$1.onResponse(BackGroundIntentService.java:110)
        at com.mi.uvite.BackGroundIntentService$1.onResponse(BackGroundIntentService.java:67)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:1)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

And

```
public class Constant_Country
{
public static String country_id = "country_id";
public static String country_short_code = "country_short_code";
public static String country_name = "country_name";
public static String country_code = "country_code";
}
```

Comment: Add the JAR that contains `com.mi.uVite.model.Constant_Country` to your classpath.

Comment: thanks for quick reply . 

Constant_Country is not in JAR its in src->java->com->mi->uVIte

Comment: Add this in your android AndroidManifest.xml <activity
            android:name="com.mi.uVite.model.Constant_Country"
            >
        </activity>

Comment: If the jar exists `NoClassDefFoundError` means there was a there was failure during classloading hence the class was not loaded. check if there are transitive dependencies

Comment: already answered here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: show your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: its not activity. Its simply java class having static variables

Comment: How you use this class variable?

Comment: `public class` ... shouldn't it be `public Class`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the class Constant_Country into the package com.mi.uVite.model and put in the first line of Constant_Country

```
package com.mi.uVite.model
```

Remember that if you use an object of type Constant_Country you have to use an import.