# com.toedter.calendar.jdatechooser error when running setup created using launch4j

Tags: java

iam using launch4j to create a .exe file, i created runnable jar file using the export option in the file menu in eclipse.the jar file runs succesfully but whenever i create a setup file in launch4j,the setup is created successfully but when it is run i get the errors in launch4j log

```
    Executing: E:\app.exe
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser
    at run$1.run(run.java:9)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 0):

See the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser
    at run$1.run(run.java:9)
```

Whenever your class is not available for the class Loader (ie your .class file) then we will get this exception.

Read the below post for better understanding:

[How to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)