# Executing a class in jar file

Tags: java, classpath

I have created an application that uses `selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar` and `javax.mail.jar`. The code works on eclipse, but I would like to run the same from command line. So I exported the project to a runnable jar file which contains both selenium and javax.mail.jar.
My code contains `RTC.java` which has the Main function and another `Ex.java`.
Both the class files are generated in com folder.
My App1.jar file is located in C:\installers.

I used the command:

```
 c:\installers> java -cp App1.jar com.RTC
```

It says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
```

Further I used:

```
 java -cp .App1.jar com.RTC
```

Then it says could not find or load main class com.RTC.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you see the `WebDriver` class inside the JAR somewhere?

Comment: I extracted the selenium jar file. There exists org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.class

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: @Ansu Well there's your problem. It should be ’org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.class`.

Comment: im sorry, but i dont understand. All I meant is there is a WebDriver.class in the folder selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I need not create a jar file which has the reference jars. I have to mention my jar which has my code and the reference jars that I am using in the class path.

My code is in App.jar.The reference jars are

selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar and 
 javax.mail.jar.

so I used
 c:\installers> java -cp selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar;javax.mail.jar;App.jar com.RTC

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

> I used the command:

```
c:\installers> java -cp App1.jar com.RTC
```

> It says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
```

That exception usually means that a .class file was found but it didn't contain the right class. Check how you're putting it into the JAR. It's directory and file name must match its package and class name.

It sometimes also seems to mean that a secondary class wasn't found. Normally secondary JAR files are mentioned in the `class-path` entry of the manifest of the main JAR file, along with the `main-class`name, so you can use

```
java -jar App1.jar
```

> Further I used:

```
java -cp .App1.jar com.RTC
```

> Then it says could not find or load main class com.RTC.

I'm not surprised. If the first command got as far as it did, the JAR filename doesn't start with a dot. Cannot imagine why you tried this. It is nonsense.