# Accessing web client file leads to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror

I am calling a class from a jar that I have already included in /libs folder in Android in eclipse.
It does not give me any error on compile time but on run time it throws me an error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

I am also getting an ART error just before this error:

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
```

I have `decompiled` the `apk` and I found that class is present in the `apk`. I have tried a lot things from cleaning the `package` to changing the order of gen and src folder.

**Note**: This class that I am calling from a jar is a web service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: Try Clean -> Build