# How to avoid a NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/PersistableBundle on pre-L?

Tags: java, android, android-reflection

I use the [TinyBus](https://github.com/beworker/tinybus) library to dispatch events in my app. MinSDK is 15, compile SDK is 23.

On pre-21 devices, I'm facing the issue which seems to affect many apps that use reflection. As soon as I try to register on the bus in my base `Activity` class (which inherits from the `AppCompatActivity`), I get the following crash log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/PersistableBundle
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodsRecursive(Class.java:955)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at de.halfbit.tinybus.impl.ObjectsMeta.<init>(ObjectsMeta.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at de.halfbit.tinybus.TinyBus.processQueue(TinyBus.java:346)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at de.halfbit.tinybus.TinyBus.register(TinyBus.java:178)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.package.name.activities.InitializedActivity.onStart(InitializedActivity.java:62)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1166)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5264)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2047)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4929)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I know that this error is caused by dalvik failing to initialize a class it can't find in the `dex` file. There is a lot of info and questions related to this issue (since it also affects Otto and others), but so far I have only seen one fix: remove the usage of `PersistableBundle` from the app. However, ***I do not reference*** `PersistableBundle` anywhere in my code, but the system apparently does.

Is there any other known fix to the problem?

Comment: Do you use proguard?

Comment: @fisher3421 sry for wasting your time, already found the (pretty much of a dumb) mistake (see my answer). Yes, I've been messing around with proguard config for quite a lot, the issue was not related to that, though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror/41669190#41669190 search my answer to this post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the issue is resolved now. After going through all of my code (which I should have done ages ago) I found out that *I actually had* references to the `PersistableBundle`. Those were located in methods I let the IDE generate like `onPostCreate(PersistableBundle bundle)` and wasn't paying attention to. Replacing all `PersistableBundle` with `Bundle` fixed the problem.

To folks having similar issue I can only suggest looking closely at the generated stuff when using newer API.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Android Studio for create project, try add method below to `Application` class:

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base){
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Remember don't forget add `multiDexEnabled true` to `gradle` file.
Help It help you.
Good luck!.

Comment: The purpose of multidex is to enable an app to reference more than `0xFFFF` methods. I cannot think of how it can help to resolve the issue described in the question.

Comment: Oh. My problem like you, when i running in device have version < 21. After I add method `attachBaseContext` in Application class, my prolem has resolve.

Comment: well I tried to enable mdex support, but magic didn't happen and the issue still persists.