# GreenRobot EventBus, ClassNotFoundException still there after using Subscriber Index

Tags: java, android, greenrobot-eventbus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I have the common "ClassNotFoundException"  [issue](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/issues/156) EventBus with a 4.4.2 device,
It's even troubleshot in the [FAQ](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/faq/)

I first double checked that I didn't use any unapropriated lifecycle methods but I didn't. Then I updated to EventBus 3.0.0, and used "suscribers index". But the bug is still here and I still can see in my stacktrace that the builder is trying to use reflexivity (`findUsingReflectionInSingleClass`):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.os.PersistableBundle" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.m360.android.debug-6.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.m360.android.debug-6, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodsRecursive(Class.java:894) 
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:877) 
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberMethodFinder.findUsingReflectionInSingleClass(SubscriberMethodFinder.java:157) 
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberMethodFinder.findUsingInfo(SubscriberMethodFinder.java:88) 
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberMethodFinder.findSubscriberMethods(SubscriberMethodFinder.java:64) 
    at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.register(EventBus.java:136) 
    at com.m360.android.activity.PlayerActivity.onStart(PlayerActivity.java:977) 
    at ...
```

In `Player Activity` :

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(QuestionFragment.EnableNextEvent event) {

    /* ...... */

}
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.builder().addIndex(new MyEventBusIndex()).build().register(this);
}
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

Also `MyEventBusIndex` is available so i guess my build files are fine.

Please let me know if you see what's the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are not overriding the onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) method in your Activity? It sounds like even just overriding it (not only calling "subscribe" within it) can cause this crash.

Comment: I double checked like I said, and since you raised a doubt I checked again. Found it in a parent of all my activities... It works fine now thanks a lot !

Comment: That's how it goes sometimes :) Cheers.

Comment: Glad you got it solved. To provide some background on why this happened with the subscriber index: findUsingReflectionInSingleClass is only called if the subscriber class is absent in the index. The question would be why...

Comment: yes, but now that I don't have a crash anymore, I don't know if the index is used or just if reflexion works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error on Galaxy s3 (android 4.3). It happens on Android where API level is below 21 and you have the direct reference to [PersistableBundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PersistableBundle.html).

"EventBus 3 with a subscriber index" didn't help to me (as and to you). 
So the workaround I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857860/classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-android-os-persistablebundle-otto-an#answer-28858364).

A bit more of the error/cause is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085681/how-to-avoid-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-os-persistablebundle-on-pre#answer-34420839).

P.S. eventbus 3.0.0

Comment: Hello, I've wiped evenbus from my project few weeks ago. I think it's for the best. thanks for the answer !