# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/Errors$Closure cause?

Tags: java

I am trying to redirect to a url which requires a security context and login ticket associated with it. I got the redirected url but not able to access it using ClientResponse.It shows  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/Errors$Closure.` I am unable to get its reason.Kindly help me with the same.

Following is code to get client response...

```
  Client restClient = Client.create();

  WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(
                            redirectUrl);

  ClientResponse resp = webResource.accept("application/json")
                            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc).header("Accept Language", "en-US")
                            .get(ClientResponse.class);
```

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace to your question.

Comment: how about this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868097/running-into-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-class-com-sun-jersey-core-header-me

Answer (score 0):

Jersey is not on your classpath at runtime, but it was at compile time.

(That is all that can be derived from your information)