# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/concept/nlview/NlviewException

Tags: java

I am integrating class file (createGraph.java) into a project where i am trying to call my createGraph's main method. I have added third party jar (Nlview.jar) into build path. When i run createGraph.java class it runs perfectly but when i call createGraph.java from existing project it throw exception

```
CreateGraph.main(arg);
```

it throw this exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/concept/nlview/NlviewException
```

what should i do

Comment: Are you using Maven, Gradle, or some other dependency management framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no i am unaware of maven or gradle

Comment: You are going to need to figure out what other dependencies you need to include.

Comment: How do you call it ?? Is it a static class ? Do you call it like that: CreateGraph.main(arg); Don't try to call main method from another class, instead create a new method and call it.