# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class impl.org.controlsfx.table.FilterPanel On Mac

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

The above error is observed while working on a Mac only. On Windows the same code of my application works fine.

Any idea about it?

Comment: To cite from **Javarevisited** http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html): 

"In short, NoClassDefFoundError will come if a class was present during compile time but not available in java classpath during runtime." Meaning, that you need to put the ControlsFX under MAC in your __classpath__.

There's a quite good explanation at the **Oracle Dos** (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)