# table.findElements(By.tagName("td") failing in RemoteWebDriver/Internet Explorer

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-grid

I have a series of Selenium tests that are ran remotely using Selenium Grid in internet Explorer.  The tests are working fine until they get to this line:

```
WebElement cart = driver.findElement(By.id("cartId");
List<WebElement> rows = cart.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); <----- fails here.
```

The code works perfectly when running locally using Chrome, and there are several steps in the remote IE test that run before that step.  If I replace `table` with `driver' (to see if the issue is somehow`findElements`) the tests pass (at that point).  There are certainly`tr` elements in the table, and the stack trace gives me no good way to figure out what is happening (which I included below). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /Users/kroe761/Documents/workspace/ecom/testng.xml

Feb 28, 2017 2:13:01 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Feb 28, 2017 2:13:04 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

FAILED: MyTest
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org/openqa/selenium/remote/server/handler/FindChildElements$1
Command duration or timeout: 80 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'kroe761-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '10.11.25.155', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=false, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, webdriver.remote.sessionid=0a293271-4edc-428e-b845-1b5ed71c0f1d, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:4747/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: 0a293271-4edc-428e-b845-1b5ed71c0f1d
*** Element info: {Using=tag name, value=tr}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElements(RemoteWebElement.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElementsByTagName(RemoteWebElement.java:270)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByTagName.findElements(By.java:327)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElements(RemoteWebElement.java:169)
    at com.company.automation.ecom.pages.checkout.Cart.getCartItemRows(Cart.java:56)
    at com.company.automation.ecom.pages.checkout.Cart.getNumOfRowsInCart(Cart.java:74)
    at com.company.automation.ecom.tests.checkout.CheckoutHelper.comparePricesOnCart(CheckoutHelper.java:59)
    at com.company.automation.ecom.tests.checkout.CheckoutCreditCard.CreditCard(CheckoutCreditCard.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/server/handler/FindChildElements$1
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindChildElements.call(FindChildElements.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindChildElements.call(FindChildElements.java:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


===============================================
    Internet Explorer
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
ECOM Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 7 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@22f71333: 5 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@7e0ea639: 11 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@7f690630: 12 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@71be98f5: 34 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter@6108b2d7: 4 ms
```

Comment: The best I can suggest is to try a selector that's more precise or specific, IE might have some subtle `html` differences that causes issues.

Answer (score 1):

According to your log this has nothing to do with Internet Explorer driver or table elements, you have classpath issues on your remote machine while executing this tests there. You are getting `NoClassDefFoundError` on `FindChildElements` class.

I don't know how your build process and project structure looks like, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror) for more details how to solve this kind of trouble.