# Addition in System.out.println not working on gedit but works fine on any IDE

Tags: java

```
class Display
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        System.out.println(x+y);
    }
}
```

> Terminal :
>
> $java Display 1 2
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory
>     at Display.main(display.java:7)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory
>     ... 1 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>     ... 1 more

Comment: Yeah, i just noticed, thanks...

Comment: The code is completely valid too. Don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Is there any problem with jdk packages?

Comment: did you save before javac?  It looks valid.

Comment: @SiddhantParekh No, the error is `NoClassDefFoundError`. Possibly, you could fix it by reading more about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: In my case the `NoClassDefFoundError` is for the classes provided by jdk.

Comment: Does it compile and run if you remove the System.out.println line?

Comment: @brt  Yes, it does.

Answer (score 1):

I think there was some problem with the jdk package.
I completely removed the packages and did a clean install, and the code worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't use the `openjdk version` but the one provided by oracle:

```
java -version
```

should print e.g.

> java version "1.8.0_151"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)

and NOT

> openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)