# Recycler View crash when fragment is destroying

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am getting a crash each time i am closing app or changing tab :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.pinmedia.mediaguide, PID: 30982
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rt
       at rs.<clinit>(SourceFile:17)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onSaveInstanceState(SourceFile:201)
       at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:12922)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:2763)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchSaveInstanceState(SourceFile:220)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2749)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2749)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2749)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2749)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2749)
       at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:12905)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentViewState(FragmentManager.java:2594)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1378)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroyView(FragmentManager.java:2943)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:2414)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1381)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:753)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using Horizontal RecyclerView inside that fragment :

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.itv_submenu_recycler_view);
// use a linear layout manager
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mAdapter = new SubMenuItemsAdapter(subMenuTabChangeListener);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

and recycler view is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/itv_submenu_recycler_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

and I am using following library for recyclerView :

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.+'
```

This issue is appearing on one phone (Kitkat devices) only.
Please help me to solve this crash. Thanks

Comment: Posible duplicate in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror]

Comment: are you saving the current state of RecyclerView?

Comment: no @AniruddhParihar

Comment: "rs, rt", looks like the class name has been obfuscated by proguard?

Comment: Out of the subject but using "getActivity()" without any check is not a good idea

Comment: This issue is appearing on one phone only.

Comment: @An-droid getActivity() is accessed in onCreateView() method of fragment.

Comment: Ok anyway that's probably unrelated to your issue. But just as example, personnally I prefer getting the Context from onAttach and dropping it in onDettach

Answer (score 1):

your using the support library 25.3.0, it can be that the phone where the crash on appears not has the latest google play services update on his phone.

to check for that

```
private void checkGooglePlayServices(){
    GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int code = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (code == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        onActivityResult(REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES, Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
    } else if (api.isUserResolvableError(code) &&
            api.showErrorDialogFragment(this, code, REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES)) {
        // wait for onActivityResult call (see below)
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, api.getErrorString(code), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                loadData();
            }
            break;

        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

what @wrkwrk sad could be a possibility but normally more phones would have problems then and not just one.

on another node try not to use the + indicator in Gradle, every time you try to build your app, Gradle has to check what the newest version is, and that only cost build-time.

Comment: on an activity call the checkGooglePlayServices this will check for you the playservices on the phone and if you need to download it. to get the responce of this override onActivityResult as given in the answer above. if Result_ok you can do what you want, if not android will send the user to the playstore to download the newest version. I use this code normally in the loading activity part to validate if everything is in order.

Comment: from which method I should call checkGooglePlayServices() ?

Comment: best place is the onStart in your loading or main page. but you have to call the function before using any support lib function or the bug will happen before the service check

Comment: Hi @quantum apps, it is going to ConnectionResult.SUCCESS , means they are updated. and this issue is occurring only on kitkat.

Comment: Samsung S3 or S4?

Comment: Samsung s4, and its appearing on Asus phone it also has kitkat. and I tested on Naughat, its working for that.

Comment: and I noticed this crash appearing only when fragment is getting destroyed from memory.