# Appium Test Error : okhttp3/ConnectionPool

Tags: appium

I'm trying to run a simple appium test case , but when executing the test this exception is throwed `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/ConnectionPool` 
for this line of code 
`AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), caps);`

the code I used is

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "blustack");
    caps.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.2");
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.sourcey.materialloginexample");
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.LoginActivity");
    caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");

    //Instantiate Appium Driver
    try {
            AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

I found a same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404956/selenium-test-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-okhttp3-connectionpool) but the proposed solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your are importing all the required jars files.

If you are using Maven project import following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are using java project, check [Adding jars for appium](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-project-in-eclipse/)