# calling a static variable?

Tags: android, class, static

I am trying to call a static variable in android but I am receiving an error.

```
URL class
public class URL{
  public static String url ="xxxxxxxx";
}

Second Class{
   private static String newUrl = MyURL.url;
}
```

but I am getting errors

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/example/system2/tranxav/url/URL;

Comment: try changing your class name

Comment: There is an answer that can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17974068/9684719

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ..

```
public class URL{
public static String url ="xxxxxxxx";
}

Class second{
private static String newUrl = URL.url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your class name properly.

```
public class MyURL{
  public static String url ="xxxxxxxx";
}
Second Class{
   private static String newUrl = MyURL.url;
}
```

this error occurs because you access url from wrong class name.