# Trying to launch firefox browser using selenium jar files in eclipse getting exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to launch the Firefox browser from Eclipse using Selenium as I'm learning Selenium.

My tutor wrote the below code but when I'm trying the same code I get this exception-

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:

The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see

[Link1](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver). The latest version can be downloaded from

[Link2](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

**Code:**

```
package appselenium1;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class A {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this exception, because you have not used gecko driver , which is required for launching and sending command in selenium.

You can download the latest version of gecko version from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Try this :

```
package appselenium1;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class A {

static WebDriver driver ; 

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
}
}
```

Comment: I tried the above  code but i got this exception-Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/exec/Executor

Comment: Did you download the latest version of gecko driver which is require for FF?

Comment: I downloaded gecko driver and I ran it.But Then I got the following exception-Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Comment: Can you tell me how to upload a screenshot into this comment. I've taken a screenshot.

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror  , and also tell us how are you executing your code, with the modification which I suggested.

Comment: I've uploaded the screenshot check out the screenshot-

Comment: @Ranjith93  :Can you check the path C:\\Download\\geckodriver

Comment: and I do not see any package , Please create one package like the one I have suggested in my answer.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQoB4.png-This is the changes that i made on eclipse

Comment: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFiL6.png- This is the file path for gecko

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` indicates that the classloader which is responsible for dynamically loading classes, cannot find the .class file for the class that you're trying to use.

Comment: This exception has nothing to do with selenium. There is something while compiling your java class , I have found one link , go through that that may resolve your problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: How do i launch browser without using gecko.Do i have to use older version of selenium.The link which you sent me above was not of much help i'm just a student, can you help me with it. @ cruisepandey

Comment: Yes you  will have to downgrade selenium version along with browser degradation , I believe that will do. Don't worry slowly you would learn.

Answer (score 0):

While you work with *Selenium ver3.x*, *GeckoDriver ver0.21.0* and *Firefox ver61.0.1*, you need to download the latest *GeckoDriver* from [mozilla/geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and store it anywhere within your system. In your code you need to provide the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* through the `System.setProperty()` line as follows:

```
package demo;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class A_Firefox 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/path/to/geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
        System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**Note**: Replace the *packagename* (**demo** in this example) with your own package name.