# Trying to add log4j in plugin type project. Error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to add Log4j.jar in plugin project for logging purpose. I add the log4j jar by using build path->add external jar. After that I am trying to run the plugin project I get error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.
>
> if I run the same code by using java main method it will working fine.

```
public HHLogger(Object className) {
    DateTimeFormatter df  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMYYYY");
    System.setProperty("filename", df.format(LocalDate.now()));
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(".\\resources\\log4j.properties");
    logger = Logger.getLogger(className.getClass());
}



public static void main(String args[]) {
    DateTimeFormatter df  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMYYYY");
    System.setProperty("filename", df.format(LocalDate.now()));
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(".\\resources\\log4j.properties");
    logger = Logger.getLogger(HHLogger.class);
    logger.info(" 999 Welcom");

}
```

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator
    at com.americanexpress.connecthotelforgbt.utility.HHLogger.(HHLogger.java:22)
    at com.americanexpress.connecthotelforgbt.parsers.OhhRqRsParser.(OhhRqRsParser.java:104)
    at com.americanexpress.connecthotelforgbt.DataIntelliSense.upshellcommand(DataIntelliSense.java:322)
    at com.americanexpress.connecthotelforgbt.listener.CommandModificationService.process(CommandModificationService.java:102)
    at com.sabre.edge.cf.core.executors.PublicServiceExecutor.decide(PublicServiceExecutor.java:143)
    at org.jbpm.graph.node.Decision.execute(Decision.java:85)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.Node.enter(Node.java:314)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.Transition.take(Transition.java:151)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.Node.leave(Node.java:389)
    at org.jbpm.graph.node.StartState.leave(StartState.java:70)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.Token.signal(Token.java:192)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.Token.signal(Token.java:140)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.ProcessInstance.signal(ProcessInstance.java:271)
    at com.sabre.edge.cf.core.flow.JBPMFlowExecutor.execute(JBPMFlowExecutor.java:45)
    at com.sabre.edge.cf.core.SRWRuntime.executeWorkflow(SRWRuntime.java:238)
    at com.sabre.edge.cf.core.SRWRuntime.process(SRWRuntime.java:173)
    at com.sabre.edge.cf.emu.bridge.EmulatorBridge.processServiceContext(EmulatorBridge.java:198)
    at com.sabre.edge.cf.emu.bridge.EmulatorBridge.updateCommand(EmulatorBridge.java:87)
    at com.sabre.stn.emulator.core.bridge.BridgeFilter.preSend(BridgeFilter.java:80)
    at com.sabre.stn.emulator.basic.model.BasicEmulatorModel.sendPreProcess(BasicEmulatorModel.java:3737)
    at com.sabre.stn.emulator.basic.model.BasicEmulatorModel.sendMessage(BasicEmulatorModel.java:3596)
    at com.sabre.stn.emulator.basic.model.BasicEmulatorModel.doEnter(BasicEmulatorModel.java:3516)
    at com.sabre.stn.emulator.basic.model.BasicEmulatorModel.enter(BasicEmulatorModel.java:1749)
    at com.sabre.stn.emulator.basic.BasicEmulator.enter(BasicEmulator.java:1979)
    at com.sabre.stn.emulator.core.EmuManager.emptyTheKeyBuffer(EmuManager.java:1132)
    at com.sabre.stn.emulator.core.KeysToScreenThread.run(KeysToScreenThread.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear, it can not find the class file of `PropertyConfigurator`
make sure that the class file  `PropertyConfigurator`is in your classpath, or  the same applies if it is in a jar file . it indicates, that `PropertyConfigurator` was found at compiletime but not at runtime. maybe you just have to add it to the classpath.

Please see this can help:  [How to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

ps: if the two classes are on the same file, you can not do that, because both are public.