# Unable to install JRuby on Windows 10

Tags: ruby, windows, jruby, install4j

I try to install `JRuby 9.2.5.0` on `Windows 10`. I tried to use JRuby 9.2.5.0 Windows Executable and x64 version installer too, but has the same effect, I got error message in a text file and installer is closed.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen  at
com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.invokeOnEDT(GUIHelper.java:711)
  at
com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.AbstractBeanConfig.finishBatch(AbstractBeanConfig.java:51)
  at
com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.registerScreens(ContextImpl.java:694)
  at
com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.start(Controller.java:75)
  at
com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:58)
  at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:45)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:85)   at
com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)   at
com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.SystemFormScreen  at
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)  at
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)   at
java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)   at
java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)  at
com.sun.beans.finder.MethodFinder$1.create(Unknown Source)  at
com.sun.beans.finder.MethodFinder$1.create(Unknown Source)  at
com.sun.beans.util.Cache.get(Unknown Source)  at
com.sun.beans.finder.MethodFinder.findMethod(Unknown Source)  at
java.beans.Statement.getMethod(Unknown Source)  at
java.beans.Statement.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)   at
java.beans.Statement.access$000(Unknown Source)   at
java.beans.Statement$2.run(Unknown Source)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.beans.Statement.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
java.beans.Expression.getValue(Unknown Source)  at
com.sun.beans.decoder.ObjectElementHandler.getValueObject(Unknown
Source)   at
com.sun.beans.decoder.NewElementHandler.getValueObject(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.beans.decoder.ElementHandler.endElement(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.beans.decoder.DocumentHandler.endElement(Unknown Source)
  at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown
Source)   at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown
Source)   at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown
Source)   at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown
Source)   at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown
Source)   at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
Source)   at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
Source)   at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
Source)   at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown
Source)   at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown
Source)   at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
Source)   at
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown
Source)   at com.sun.beans.decoder.DocumentHandler$1.run(Unknown
Source)   at com.sun.beans.decoder.DocumentHandler$1.run(Unknown
Source)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
Source)   at com.sun.beans.decoder.DocumentHandler.parse(Unknown
Source)   at java.beans.XMLDecoder$1.run(Unknown Source)  at
java.beans.XMLDecoder$1.run(Unknown Source)   at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.beans.XMLDecoder.parsingComplete(Unknown Source)   at
java.beans.XMLDecoder.readObject(Unknown Source)  at
com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.AbstractBeanConfig$2.call(AbstractBeanConfig.java:54)
  at
com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.AbstractBeanConfig$2.call(AbstractBeanConfig.java:51)
  at
com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper$4.run(GUIHelper.java:701)
  at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)  at
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)   at
java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)  at
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)   at
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)   at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Maybe it have something to do with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: @BladeMight : I see, but it is a prebuilt installer, an exe file.

Comment: Looks like anti-virus-software quarantining the i4jruntime.jar file in the temporary directory

Comment: @IngoKegel: There aren't any additional antivirus software installed on it.

Comment: Would be interesting to see the log file from the temporary directory, that's a file that starts with "i4j_log".

Comment: Search was unable to find this folder. Where is it located?