# Why do I get a ClassNotFoundException when the class exists

Tags: java, package, classnotfoundexception

I have a folder on my computer where I store all my code for every language and within this folder I have a folder with my java codes and projects. Currently I have the following layout in terms of folders and files:

```
Java
    /TD3
        /fr
            /insalyon
                /tc
                    /framework
                        Main.java
                        Main.class
                        JeuCombinatoire.java
                        JeuCombinatoire.class
        /Jeux
            Wythoff.java
            Wythoff.class
            Nim.java
            Nim.class
            EnsembleDeJeux.java
            EnsembleDeJeux.class
```

All the files in `Jeux` import JeuCombinatoire from the other directory with `import fr.insalyon.tc.framework.JeuCombinatoire;` but my issues resides in the execution of `Main.java`. Everything is compiled correctly other than a use of a deprecated api somewhere which isn't too important. When I run `java Main` from within the framework folder, I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` so I added a `.class` to the end and now I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

I'm not quite sure why this is happening nor how to get past this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting the Main class into the Juex package (i.e declaration: package Juex ; to it), set the classpath to parent folder (folder containing Juex), and then compile it. I am guessing you ran it using java from the command line. Other solutions are for  Eclipse and IntelliJ, but they have similar concepts.
Hope this will help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: I tried your solution and it's close, turns out I need the main out of both packages and then it works. Not 100% why, guess I'll have to read online about it.