# Error: Unable to initialize main class StartServer Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/PortableServer/Servant

Tags: java, corba

**The structure of my project**

[image: The structure of my project]

When I try to run my server code, the error shows up

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=62557:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\untitled\out\production\untitled StartServer
```

**Error**

```
Unable to initialize main class StartServer
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/PortableServer/Servant
```

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: What version of Java are you running? The Corba classes were removed at some point around or after 1.9.