# Stripe.apiKey error when running java project using Maven

Tags: maven, stripe-payments

I'm trying to follow Stripe example here: https://stripe.com/docs/development

The code from the example:

```
import com.stripe.Stripe.*;
//... other import ...

public class TestStripe
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_xxxxxxx";
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("amount", 1000);
        params.put("currency", "usd");
        ArrayList paymentMethodTypes = new ArrayList();
        paymentMethodTypes.add("card");
        params.put("payment_method_types", paymentMethodTypes);
        params.put("receipt_email", "jenny.rosen@example.com");
        try
        {
           PaymentIntent.create(params);
        }
        catch (Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
  }
```

I can compile and package in `Maven` just fine. But when I run it, I got error as below.  It stopped at the line with "`Stripe.apiKey=...`" above.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/stripe/Stripe
        at com.mycompany.app.TestAPI.main(TestStripe.java:XX)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.stripe.Stripe
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 1 more
```

Here is my POM dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.stripe</groupId>
  <artifactId>stripe-java</artifactId>
  <version>19.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

How do I resove this?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually installing the Stripe library?  Does it work if you use `import com.stripe.Stripe` (without the wildcard)?

Comment: @floatingLomas I'm not sure whether it was actually installing the Stripe library. I'm quite new on this.
I've changed to only import 'com.stripe.Stripe' and got the same error.

Comment: This sounds like a more general Java issue maybe?  This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17974068/379538

Comment: I tried the same code and pom using Eclipse with Maven project.  It can compile, package, and run.  
So I think may be when I compile and package with command line. It didn't really download dependencies for me.  Comparing with under project created by Eclipse, it has all dependency Jars downloaded under project folder.
So I think it is something about using Maven command line.

Comment: I've just found out that Maven was actually downloaded Stripe depency to ./m2 folder.  Then I copied POM from Eclipse project and replace POM in my original Maven project (the one not on Eclipse).  Now when I compile, package, and run TestStripe, I 've got another error instead.  See below:
  
'Error: Unable to initialize main class TestStripe'
'Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/stripe/exception/SignatureVerificationException'