# I want to upload video on aws s3 server but not able to build connection from my app to server

Tags: java, amazon-s3

It shows error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory] with root cause.
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory

am using code:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withRegion(clientRegion)
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
    .build();
```

Comment: This generally indicates that the class definition was not found in CLASSPATH or was not defined in manifest file's ClassPath attribute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)