# Issue in importing org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook; in selenium Java project

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation, xssf

I am having issue in importing xssfWorkbook. I have added poi.xml files externally and added dependencies in my pom file. Bu[image]t still the eclipse shows error as import cannot be resolved.

Comment: Did you add external  jar files into your projrct library ?

Comment: Yes I did...I have updated the maven as well..but again some issues going on as "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook"..any help here?

Comment: Hey this link will help you to resolve this **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror**

Comment: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html