# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Tags: java

My java version:

```
java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I'm trying to run a .jar file from command line in windows 10 but still I'm getting below error

```
C:\Users\admin>java -jar E:\cupcarbon\tmp\cupcarbon.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class cupcarbon.CupCarbon
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

I have downloaded openjfx externally and provided the path as well but still the same error

Comment: Did you create the jar file? If you did, please add your file structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file structure of the source is set up incorrectly. To extract the original files, use `jar xf jar-file [archived-file(s)]`, and look for main.java. Also have a look at this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136420/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javafx-application-application.