# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver at Driverbasic.Driverbasics.main(Driverbasics.java:12)

Tags: java, selenium, automation

i am getting the above error .I have import all the libs related to selenium and java .Here is the code that i have written

package Driverbasic;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Driverbasics {

```
public static void main (String args [])
{
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/user/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.29.1-linux64");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

}

Here is the error i am getting

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver
at Driverbasic.Driverbasics.main(Driverbasics.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 1 more
I have attached the screenshot for the same .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iYTm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHc2J.png)

Any help would be really appreciated .

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: How are you handling dependencies in your project?