# Java jrpc runtime error in ManagedChannelImplBuilder

Tags: java, maven, google-bigquery, gson, dependency-management

I am using a spring boot application to use Bigquery as well as Google cloud SQL. I am getting a runtime error as follows.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'annotationDAO': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'bigQueryRepository'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'bigQueryRepository' defined in URL
> [jar:file:/statistics-service.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/stl/sciocardio/webapp/statistics/repository/BigQueryRepository.class]:
> Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [com.stl.sciocardio.webapp.statistics.repository.BigQueryRepository]:
> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> io/grpc/internal/ManagedChannelImplBuilder$ChannelBuilderDefaultPortProvider

Part of my pom is as follows.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.14</version>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-datastore</artifactId>
            <version>1.97.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
            <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquerystorage</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-transport-native-kqueue</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

I think this is a dependency issue because this error came after adding that gson library. Any clue to solve this issue? I am using maven 3

Comment: Have you tried downgrading gson to 2.9.1 or upgrading google-cloud-bigquery to 2.18.2 to match with gson version?

Comment: @YuriGolobokov, I tried. It didn't work.

Comment: Why do you have an exclusion for `<groupId>*</groupId>` and `<artifactId>*</artifactId>` for Gson? Gson has no dependencies so this should not be needed, though it probably also has no negative effect. Could you please try to debug your application to find the underlying cause for the `NoClassDefFoundError` (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/21303729). Possibly the initalizer of the class threw an exception (in that case please provide its stack trace).