# Getting exception - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/Range

Tags: java

I'm trying to use StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava() in my code.The StringEscapeUtils is in,

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;
```

But I'm getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/Range
    at org.apache.commons.text.translate.NumericEntityEscaper.<init>(NumericEntityEscaper.java:97)
    at org.apache.commons.text.translate.NumericEntityEscaper.between(NumericEntityEscaper.java:59)
    at org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.<clinit>(StringEscapeUtils.java:271)
    at tesa.frame.ez.EZFacadeFrame.fireAlert(EZFacadeFrame.java:473)
    at tesa.frame.ez.EZFacadeFrame.runFrameLogic(EZFacadeFrame.java:175)
    at tesa.frame.Frame.run(Frame.java:186)
    at tesa.frame.Frame.run(Frame.java:146)
    at tesa.event.processors.AbstractEventProcessor.runFrame(AbstractEventProcessor.java:942)
    at tesa.event.processors.EQAlertEventProcessor.runEvent(EQAlertEventProcessor.java:255)
    at tesa.event.processors.AbstractEventProcessor.runAgenda(AbstractEventProcessor.java:770)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.Range
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 14 more
```

Please help thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-can-i-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: Have you added dependency for that library ?

Comment: Use maven to manage your dependencies.

Comment: It is a plain java code. I have added the jar - commons-text-1.10.0