# compilation error , wrong package name in java

Tags: java

I am trying to compile this code but I get this error "Error: Could not find or load main class Program
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Program (wrong name: module00/ex00/Program)"

[image]

Comment: Package and Module are two different things in Java. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [*How can I solve "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17973970/642706).